# Conflict on Overloading

Tags: java, overloading

This question is bothering me for a while.Please help

Suppose there are two methods

```
public void add(Object obj){
/* some logic*/
}

public void add(String str){
/*Some logic*/
}
```

so when i call `add(null)` which method will get executed and why?

thanks

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: but on what bases jvm considers most **specfic** type?its still unclear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the `String` argument version wins, because `String` is a more specific type as  every class is a subclass of `Object` (except itself).

Anyway, you'll still be able to call the `Object` argument version by casting.

e.g.

```
app.add((Object) null);
```

If there're more than one potential match, such as having a version of `add(Integer i)` version available, it's an error, and won't compile.

Comment: if specific type wins then what about this `add(Integer sum)` and `add(String str)`?

Comment: @vicky, then it won't compile, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will call method with String argument...

classes in Java are direct or indirect subclasses of Object. So String is a subtype of Object, the method overloaded to accept a String is more specific than the method overloaded to accept an Object. A String can be converted (upcast) to Object, but an Object cannot be converted (downcast or upcast) to String, so the method taking the String argument is more specific. Therefore, print(String s) will be invoked by the call print(null).